# How to expose native to managed - C++/CLI on x64 Platform

Tags: c++, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have a static lib in my project and I want to use this in my .net project.
I have taken this project as a starting point.
[Exposing native to managed - C++/CLI](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651516/Exposing-native-to-managed-Cplusplus-CLI-vs-P-Invo?msg=5908609#xx5908609xx)

My use case is the Second Approach.

So far everything works, but when I change the architecture from x86 to x64 I get a lot of linker errors:

[image]

Currently I do not understand where the problem is and why these errors come:

Comment: Do you change library when switching architecture? If not the linker would look for the wrong mangled names.

Comment: You are right, paths were the same for all build. After path separation it works now.

Comment: @Lasersköld would you like to post you guess as answer, so I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Sure, nice to see that it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you change library when switching architecture? If not the linker would look for the wrong mangled